# How do I create a Formik and yup form component which has 3 inputs but maps to 1 yup value?

Tags: javascript, datepicker, formik, yup

How do i basically create this https://design-system.service.gov.uk/patterns/dates/ in formik with yup validation.

[image]

so the 3 fields `day`, `month` and `year` would create merge to one `{date: [moment]}` to be validated by yup ?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find anything out yet?

Comment: yh i used `setFieldValue`... ill answer with what i did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used `setFieldValue`.

```js
class DatePicker extends React.Component {
  state = {
    day: '',
    month: '',
    year: ''
  };

  updateDateValue = () => {
    const {day, month, year} = this.state;
    const { field } = this.props;
    let momentDate = '';

    if (day && month && year) {
      const date = moment(`${year}-${month}-${day}T00:00:00+0:00Z`, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z');

      if (date.isValid()) {
        momentDate = date.utc().format();
      }
    };
    this.props.form.setFieldValue(field.name, momentDate, true);
  };

  handleDayChange = (event) => this.setState({day: event.target.value}, () => this.updateDateValue());
  handleMonthChange = (event) => this.setState({month: event.target.value}, () => this.updateDateValue());
  handleYearChange = (event) => this.setState({year: event.target.value}, () => this.updateDateValue());

  render() {
    const {day, month, year} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="datePicker">
          <input value={day} label="Day" name="day" onChange={this.handleDayChange} />
          <input value={month} label="Month" name="month" onChange={this.handleMonthChange} />
          <input value={year} label="Year" name="year" onChange={this.handleYearChange} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```